# How to repair cracks in concrete floor after a slab leak?

Tags: leak, slab, cracks

Had a cold water leak in pipe under slab. Water came through cracks in floor. What is best and inexpensive way to repair the cracks?

Comment: we really need pic to know what you are dealing with here.  There may be nothing needed to be done.

Comment: Where are the cracks? How extensive are they? Because this could be everything from 'ignore' to 'fix with concrete caulk' to 'major foundation repair', with a strong bias toward the first one.

Comment: Is the intent to seal the cracks for aesthetic reasons, or are you trying to seal them hydraulically (which probably isn't really possible)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.